# C++ /// How do i append a value to an int variable with for and if loop

Tags: c++

as the title says, i'm currently confused on how to append a value from an array of char, into an Int variable. i know how to get around this in python but i'm really new to c++ and I've been trying to look for a solution online but there just isn't any.

so anyway here's my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char studentId[9];
    cout << "Enter Student ID : ";
    cin >> studentId

    int n;
    cout << "\nYour special number is ";
    for (n=1; n<(sizeof(studentId)); n+=2)
    {
        cout << studentId[n]; //this displays all numbers in even places, this one works
    }


    char oddId[8];
    for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
    {
        if (studentId[c] % 2 != 0)
        {
            oddId[c] = studentId[c];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nOdd numbers after the for loop : " << oddId;
    int oddInt = stoi(oddId);
    cout << "\nOdd numbers after converted to Int : " << oddInt; // i need to convert the odd numbers to int so i can get the remainder
    cout << "\nYour lucky number is " << oddInt % 9 << endl; //remainder of odd numbers when divided by 9


    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output

[image: output]

Thank you so much in advance, been trying to figure this out for 3 days now.

[Edit]

This is what i did in python, might be a mess but it works how i want it to be :

```
def magic(num_list):
s = ''.join(map(str, num_list))
return(int(s))

std_id = input("Enter Student ID: ")

id_list = []
for a in std_id:
    id_list.append(a)

id_no = list(map(int, id_list))

even_list = id_no[1::2]

odd_list = []
for x in id_no:
    if x % 2 == 1:
        odd_list.append(x)

oddodd = magic(odd_list)
eveneven = magic(even_list)

print("Your special number is", eveneven)
print("Your lucky number is", oddodd % 9)
```

Comment: I fail to understand what do you mean by "*append a value from an array of char, into an Int variable*". Do you want to convert `char[]` containing only digits (and maybe leading `'-'`) to an `int` variable?

Comment: sorry about that i'm still learning programming terms. basically, yeah, i want to convert my "oddId" (which is char) into an int variable, so i can use the "%" operator on it

Comment: Seems there's a disconnect at least terminologically in what you're asking. What does the code look like in Python to do what you want? Show that code and I suspect that'll make more sense of things for people to respond to. Thanks!

Comment: You're not filling in some of the elements of `oddid`.

Comment: `stoi()` expects a **null-terminated** sequence of characters, aka `string`. Make your `char[]`s 1 character longer and add `'\0'` as the last `char`

Comment: @LouisLangholtz i added the python version of this code, thank you for the suggestion !

Comment: There doesn’t exist a if loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this part of the code:

```
char oddId[8];
for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
{
    if (studentId[c] % 2 != 0)
    {
        oddId[c] = studentId[c];
    }
}
```

First, `oddId` isn't big enough. To hold an 8-digit string, you need 9 elements, because you need a null terminator.

Second, you're using the same index `c` for the input array and the output array. This means that the elements of `oddId` that correspond to the even elements of `studentId` will never be filled in. That's why you see all those garbage characters in the middle of the output.

Third, you never add a null terminator when you're done. That's why you see more garbage characters at the end of the output.

Fourth, if the input string is less than 8 characters long, you'll read past the end of it. You need to use `strlen()` to get the limit. You should also use this in the earlier loop that prints all the even places, instead of `sizeof(studentId)`.

Try this:

```
char oddId[9];
int indexout = 0;
int len = strlen(studentId);
for (int indexin = 0; indexin < len; indexin++)
{
    if (studentId[indexin] % 2 != 0)
    {
        oddId[indexout++] = studentId[indexin];
    }
}
oddId[indexout] = '\0';
```

BTW, things would be much easier if you used `std::string` instead of a C-style string, since it supports concatenation.

Comment: okay you probably meant to type "indexin++" in the for statement right ? i did just that and it worked! thank you so much! i didn't expect responses this fast ^^

Comment: i'm still trying to understand how your code works though, i didn't even know i used this "C-style string"

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = 0;
for(int ndx = 0; count != ndx; ++ndx)
{
  value *= 10;
  value += str[ndx] - '0';
}
```

Assumes  the length is already known and that all characters are between 0 and 9 inclusive.